# Navigation with Material-UI Icons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-navigation

How can I use a Material-UI Icon to do navigation using React router Dom?

I tried this but this doesn't work:

```
 <NavigateBeforeIcon path="/vehicles"></NavigateBeforeIcon>
```

In case of Buttons, I could do something like `component={Link}` and `to="/vehicles"` but I can't figure out how to navigate directly from the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [useHistory](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) Hook:

import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

```
function Home() {
  const history = useHistory();

  return <NavigateBeforeIcon onClick={() => history.push('/profile')}
          ></NavigateBeforeIcon>
}
```

With it you can build a custom component.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this way? Material-UI now supports Icon Button components,

```
<IconButton aria-label="vehicles" component={Link} to="/vehicles">
  <NavigateBeforeIcon />
</IconButton>
```

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ifgg2

I found it weird that I couldn't find your exact icon from the Icon pack. I replaced that icon with a working sample icon. However, This could help you to identify and use as proof for my answer.

Refer to this: https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#icon-buttons

I hope this will help you!

Comment: I get overloading errors on component ```Type '{ children: Element; "aria-label": string; component: typeof Link; to: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<IconButton> & Readonly<IconButtonProps> & Readonly<...>'.```

Comment: Could you please mention the Material UI version you are using?

Comment: ```"@material-ui/core": "latest",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",```

Comment: I updated the answer with a working sample. please check. please note that I couldn't find your icon. I replaced it with an existing one.

Comment: Even if I try with a different icon, it's not working. I am using TypeScript.

Comment: In the documentation too, I see the aria-label attribute but there's no example with component and to

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-router-dom's useHistory hook or from props to push a path whenever the icon is clicked.

```js
const Sidepane = () => {

// Assuming that you've imported it from the react-router-dom package

const history = useHistory()

const onClick = () => history.push("/vehicles") 

return (
        <NavigateBeforeIcon onClick={onClick}>
           Go to vehicles 
        </NavigateBeforeIcon

        )

}
```

I hope this helps